# vb and Outlook - show only messages from contact using vb code(from access)

Tags: ms-access, search, vba, outlook

Using Office 2010.

In access I have a form containing contact information of clients.

A button next to the e-mail of the client **OPENS OUTLOOK** and applies a filter to display only the e-mails from that client in **OUTLOOK**.

```
Private Sub filterOutlook_Click()
   'bit of code here which checks if outlook is open, if not then"
   Shell "Outlook.exe /cleanviews"

   'email of contact field(hyperlink) is retreived
   contactname = Left$([E-mail contact].Value, InStr([E-mail contact].Value, "#") - 1)

   filtermail contactname
End Sub
```

The filtermail function is as follows:

```
Public Sub filtermail(name As String)

Dim objView As View
Set objView = outlook.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView

    If LenB(name) = 0 Then
        objView.Filter = vbNullString
    Else
        objView.Filter = _ 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001f CI_STARTSWITH '" & name & "'"
    End If

objView.Save
objView.Apply

End Sub
```

The code works fine, but only applies the filter to the folder currently open in **OUTLOOK**.

If you have multiple accounts you would have to first open the inbox or sent folder and then apply the filter. Rather cumbersome.

I would like to replace the code above to one where I can control the searchbar in outlook.
[Search Bar](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/outlook/WindowsLiveWriter/BetterSearchinginOutlook2010_DFBB/image_4.png)

So selecting "All Mail Items" or "All Outlook Items", ranking the result by account or date and using the following queries "system.structuredquery.virtual.from:(name)" and "to:(name)".

Using the searchbar manually gives me the result I want. I can see all the history with a client across different accounts and folders. But having it automated would be great.

Is it possible and how can I achieve this.

In summation: when button clicked next to e-mail, open outlook and show messages from and to that e-mail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
Public Sub filtermail(name As String)

Dim myOlApp As New outlook.Application

    If LenB(name) = 0 Then
        myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.ClearSearch
    Else
        myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search "from:(" & name & ") OR to:(" & name & ")", olSearchScopeAllFolders
    End If

Set myOlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Needs a bit of testing, but works for now.
To call the function/sub see code posted in 1st post.